# How can I detect when a web page finishes loading in a WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, internet-explorer, browser

I'm talking about that "webbrowser" control which uses internet explorer.
How can I detect when it finishes loading?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Always look for events in such cases. In this case, [`DocumentCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx) event.

Answer (score 3):

Subscribe to the WebBrowser control's DocumentCompleted event. i.e.

```
this.webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(this.WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted);

private void WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  // Do stuff here
}
```